# passing an object to a method taking int Java

Tags: java

I am doing a sudoku for school. Here I am trying to place a number inside an empty grid. I have a constructor that gives initialise 3 variables, I then created an object with three value. I want to pass those three value of each object inside my grid, here is my code.

```
public  int [][]  insertNumber(int x, int y , int z){
    isOnRow(x,z);
    isOnColomn(y,z);
    isOnBlock(x,y,z);
    tableau [x][y] = z;
    return tableau;          
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Case> contenantCase = new ArrayList<>();
    Case objetCase1 = new Case(0,1,4);
    Case objetCase2 = new Case(0,2,3);
    Case objetCase3 = new Case(0,3,7);
    contenantCase.add(objetCase1);
    contenantCase.add(objetCase2);
    contenantCase.add(objetCase3);

    insertNumber(objetCase1);
    printGrille();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your Case class looks like, but either you change your insertNumber() method to accept a Case object or you need to call it like so:

```
insertNumber(objectCase1.x, objectCase.y, objectCase.z);
```

Assuming that Case class has 3 fields x, y and z.

Comment: Thanks alot it makes sens!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer as correct then.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code this is what i did with new parameter in same class.

```
// also applicable with static to use it on the fly.
public static class NumberInserter() {
     private int x,y,z;
     private case _case;
     NumberInserter() {}
     NumberInserter(int x, int y, int z) {}
     NumberInserter(Case case) { _case = case; }

public  int [][]  doInt(){
    isOnRow(x,z);
    isOnColomn(y,z);
    isOnBlock(x,y,z);
    tableau [x][y] = z;
    return tableau;          
}
public  int [][]  doCase(){
    isOnRow(case.x, case.z);
    isOnColomn(case.y,case.z);
    isOnBlock(case.x, case.y,case.z);
    tableau [case.x][case.y] = case.z;
    return tableau;          
}

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Case> contenantCase = new ArrayList<>();
    Case objetCase1 = new Case(0,1,4);
    Case objetCase2 = new Case(0,2,3);
    Case objetCase3 = new Case(0,3,7);
    contenantCase.add(objetCase1);
    contenantCase.add(objetCase2);
    contenantCase.add(objetCase3);

    NumberInserter(objetCase1).doCase();
    printGrille();
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of the case in your number inserter method? especially this line NumberInserter(Case case) { _case = case; }

Comment: @BroncoBilly Constructor chaining is the method to achieve polymorphism. So u can pass value in primitive types or objects to your class and return expected value.